# PHP session NOT captured

Tags: php, session, authentication

I developed my own login.php, however, the login is success but the session is not being captured. Every time I proceed to another link, it will bring me back to login.php and demand for me to re-login again. I did try using $_SESSION (as commented) but the come out the login page unable to login entirely.

Thank in advance

Below is my code

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $uid = $_POST["uid"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 } 


include("src/db.php");
session_start();

if(!isset($uid)) {

//if(!isset($_SESSION['$uid'])){

?>

<MY HTML code -- Let me know if you need to check my HTML as well>

<?php
exit;
  }

 dbConnect("myDB");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_user WHERE username = '$uid' AND password =  '$password'";

$result = pg_exec($sql);
$dept_id = pg_result($result,0,"dept_id");
if (pg_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['dept_id'] = $dept_id;

}

?>
<?
// ** THIS IS THE NEW SECTION **
//if ((pg_numrows($result) == 1) AND ($access != 'Y')) {


// ** END OF NEW SECTION **
?>
<?

if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
//session_unregister("uid");
//session_unregister("password");
// session_unregister("dept_id");
unset($_SESSION["uid"]);
unset($_SESSION["password"]);
unset($_SESSION["dept_id"]);

?>
```

Comment: The issue is how you check if that session has been populated before. `isset($uid)` obviously will _not_ work, since the `uid` is stored in `$_SESSION['uid']` which is something different. You were _nearly_ there with that conditional you commented out, but you confused `'uid'` with `'$uid'`...

Comment: at the top of your code add 'session_start();'

Comment: hi @arkascha , am I declaring the $uid wrongly ? because I can't declare it as isset(uid), it will not functioning at all...

Comment: hi @MasivuyeCokile , I did add it after include("src/db.php"); .. should I add it somewhere else ?

Comment: You don't declare `$uid` _at all_, unless in a `POST` request.

Comment: Hi @arkascha ,overlooked on that, my bad... sorry my PHP skill is not that good, how should I declare the $uid since i already declare the same for POST ?

Comment: You check both, a potential `POST` request _and_ a potentially existing session variable. If none exists, you forward to your authentication form.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() move to top of your file.

Comment: hi @dhiren, not working as well.. thanks for you reply btw

Comment: Also your this code 'dbConnect("myDB");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_user WHERE username = '$uid' AND password =  '$password'";

$result = pg_exec($sql);
$dept_id = pg_result($result,0,"dept_id");
if (pg_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['dept_id'] = $dept_id;

}' move under the this if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")